# To access these functions and variables elsewhere inside the class (Python)

Tags: python, oop

I am following a tutorial from: http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson08/

I do not understand the following:

> Any function or variable created on the first level of indentation
>   (that is, lines of code that start one TAB to the right of where we
>   put class Shape is automatically put into self. To access these
>   functions and variables elsewhere inside the class, their name must be
>   preceded with self and a full-stop (e.g. self.variable_name).

Here is part of the example used:

```
#An example of a class
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
```

I understand how self.x affects __ init __ part of the code, but not for functions because they seem to play by different rules (e.g.  i cannot access variables from inside functions)... In other words, i'm trying to figure out what self.x is doing in the functions. if I put only x in the function what does it do? If I put x in __ int __ it only 'lives' in __ int and cannot be called when I make an object . If I put self.x in __int it can be called when I make an object. I am wondering about self.x vs x in functions because I cannot figure out code to test it

Comment: Are you sure the indentation in your post is what the example shows as well? There was a preview of your question while writing it, but maybe you missed it.

Comment: Since your question seems to be primarily about indentation, and the indentation of your example is clearly wrong, it's pretty hard to answer. Also, can you try to reword the last sentence? I don't know what most of it means. For example, what do you mean "`__init__` part of the code, but not for functions"? (`__init__` is a function, just like `area`; what distinction were you trying to make?) And also, what do you mean by "I cannot access variables from inside functions"? Show us the code that you tried to write, and how it didn't work (or didn't work as expected/desired).'

Comment: By the way, there are a few things in that tutorial that aren't quite true. They're more in the way of "imprecise to make it easier to understand" than "actively misleading", but be aware that things like "No code is run when you define a class" and even the line you ask about, "Any function or variable created on the first level of indentation… is automatically put into self" are not really true as written, so if you try to dig too deeply into them, you will mislead yourself in a way the author probably didn't intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand how self.x affects __ init __ part of the code, but not for functions because they seem to play by different rules (e.g. i cannot access variables from inside functions)...

No, they really don't play by different rules. `__init__` is just a function, defined in a `class` definition, exactly like `area`.

They both take `self` as an explicit parameter, and have to use that `self` if they want to access or set instance attributes like `x`, or call instance methods like `describe`.

The only difference is how they're called:

- `area` is something that you call directly. When you write `my_shape.area()`, that calls the `area` function passing `my_shape` as the value of `self`.
- `__init__` is something that Python calls automatically. When you write `my_shape = Shape(2, 3)`, Python constructs a new `Shape` object, and then calls the `__init__` function passing that new object as `self` (and `2` and `3` as `x` and `y`).

> In other words, i'm trying to figure out what self.x is doing in the functions. if I put only x in the function what does it do?

Plain old `x` is a local variable if you have one, a global variable if you don't. So, inside `__init__`, where there's a parameter named `x`, it's that `x` (e.g., it's `2` in the `Shape(2, 3)` example). Inside `area`, where there is nothing local named `x`, it would be a global variable. But you probably don't have a global named `x` either, so it would raise a `NameError`.

`self.x`, on the other hand, is the `x` attribute of whatever `self` is. As explained above, `self` is a newly-created `Shape` instance inside `__init__`, and whatever `Shape` instance you called `area` on inside `area`.

---

> If I put x in __ int __ it only 'lives' in __ int and cannot be called when I make an object .

Yes, if you define something named `x` in `__init__`, it's a local variable, so it only lives within `__init__`. That's true for *any* function—not just `__init__`, not even just methods defined in a class; that's what local variables mean. Once the function ends, those variables are gone, and nobody can ever access them again. (This isn't quite true if closures are involved, but they aren't here, so ignore that.)

I don't know what you mean by "called", because you don't normally call values that aren't functions/methods/classes, and I don't know what you mean by "when I make an object", because when you make an object is exactly when `__init__` gets called.

> If I put self.x in __int it can be called when I make an object.

Anything you assign to `self.x` inside `__init__` gets stored as part of that `self` instance. So, it can be accessed again by anyone who has that instance. For example, inside `area`, you can access it as `self.x`. Or, from top-level code, you can access it as `my_shape.x`.

Again, there's nothing special about `__init__` here; you could do the same thing in another method—as the `describe` method does. You could even do it from outside the object.

For example:

```
>>> my_shape = Shape(2, 3)
>>> my_shape.x
2
>>> my_shape.area()
6
>>> my_shape.x = 4
>>> my_shape.area()
12
```

Again, I don't know what you mean by "called" or by "when I make an object".

> I am wondering about self.x vs x in functions because I cannot figure out code to test it

Try adding this method:

```
def play_with_x(self):
    x = 10
    print(x)
    print(self.x)
    x = 20
    print(x)
    print(self.x)
    self.x = 30
    print(x)
    print(self.x)
```

Then try this:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> my_shape = Shape(2, 3)
>>> my_shape.play_with_x()
```

You'll see that it can change `x` and `self.x`. They're completely independent of each other, but mostly seem to act the same from within one function. But now:

```
>>> x
0
>>> my_shape.x
30
```

That `x = 20` didn't do anything to the global variable `x`. But that `self.x = 30` did permanently change `self`, which is the same object as `my_shape`, so `my_shape.x` is now 30.

Comment: Thank you so much. You make stackoverflow amazing! :_)

Comment: I think I get it after reading it a few times: 1) x outside a function creates a global variable and the obj cannot inherit x as a global variable. 2) x inside of a function creates a local variable and the obj cannot inherit x as a local variable. 3) self.x outside a function creates a global variable that an object inherits (from its class) as a global variable. 4) self.x inside of a function creates a local variable that an object inherits as a local variable.

Comment: @NeverTellMeTheStack You're right for 1) and 2), but "obj cannot inherit x" is weird terminology here—you don't inherit variables. Methods in `obj`'s type can access either kind of `x`, but neither kind is part of the object. 1) is shared with the whole program, 2) is just local to that method. Meanwhile, 3) doesn't make sense—you can only do `self.x` where `self` exists, which generally means only inside a method (where it's the first parameter). 4) is wrong; `self.x` does _not_ create a local variable, it creates an attribute on `self`, which (unlike a local variable) can be accessed later.